# adding two extra columns of data into .csv file based on the generated parameter values

Tags: bash

So basically I have 1071 (21*51) amount of .log files, what the following code does here is:
 1. extract a specific column of data
 2. calculate the cumulative moving average and save the average numbers into .csv files

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/Projekt/output/12beads900K/original

for b in 12;
do
 for t in `printf "0.%02d " {1..21}` ;
 do
  for a in `printf "0.%02d " {0..50}`;
  do
  #extract a specific column of data from 21*50 amount of .log file#
  grep '0,' b${b}_t${t}_a${a}.log | tail -n+3 | awk '{ print  $7}' |\
   sed 's/\,//g' | sed 's/\ /\,/g' > /Users/Projekt/output/12beads900K//log/b${b}_t${t}_a${a}.log

 #calculate the cumulative moving average#
  count=0;
  total=0;
  average=0;

   for i in $( awk '{ print $1; }' /Users/Projekt/output/12beads900K/log/b${b}_t${t}_a${a}.log )
   do
     total=$(echo $total + $i | bc)
     ((count++))

   average=`echo "scale=19; $total/$count" | bc -l`
   echo $count, $average >> /Users/Projekt/output/12beads900K/b${b}_t${t}_a${a}.csv
   done
 #end of the calculation#

  done
 done
done
```

I also want to make another 2 column of data into each of my .csv files, the corresponding `t` and `a` value. 
The final output of each file should be like:

```
   1 0.056 0.01 0.00
   2 0.057 0.01 0.01
   3 0.055 0.01 0.02
   .   .     .   .
   .   .     .   .
   .   .     .   .
  50 0.057 0.01 0.50
  51 0.056 0.02 0.00
  52 0.055 0.02 0.01
   .   .     .   .
   .   .     .   .
   .   .     .   .
1071 0.056 0.21 0.50
```

I tried to do `echo $t, $a` in the average calculation loop, then I realised that the value will be re-written as the calculation updates. If I bring it outside of the loop, it will only print out the final value. Appreciate if anyone can give me some hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jkrainer, the `paste` command here does the job!

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/Projekt/output/12beads900K/original

for b in 12;
do
 for t in `printf "0.%02d " {1..21}` ;
 do
  for a in `printf "0.%02d " {0..50}`;
  do
  #extract a specific column of data from 21*50 amount of .log file#
  grep '0,' b${b}_t${t}_a${a}.log | tail -n+3 | awk '{ print  $7}' |\
   sed 's/\,//g' | sed 's/\ /\,/g' > /Users/Projekt/output/12beads900K//log/b${b}_t${t}_a${a}.log

#calculate the cumulative moving average#
count=0;
total=0;
average=0;

 for i in $( awk '{ print $1; }'/Users/Projekt/output/12beads900K/log/b${b}_t${t}_a${a}.log )
 do
 total=$(echo $total + $i | bc)
 ((count++))

 average=`echo "scale=19; $total/$count" | bc -l`
echo $count, $average >> /Users/Projekt/output/12beads900K/b${b}_t${t}_a${a}.csv
done
#end of the calculation#

#generate a temp.csv file that stores the incrementing parameters in order and merge with the former file##

 echo $t, $a >> /Users/Projekt/output/12beads900K/temp.csv
 paste temp.csv b${b}_t${t}_a${a}.csv | sed 's/\t/ /'

  done
 done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want your `.csv` file to look like that:

```
$count, $average, $t, $a
```

To do that you could add it to your `echo` command:

```
echo $count, $average, $t, $a >> /Users/Projekt/output/12beads900K/b${b}_t${t}_a${a}.csv
```

Comment: no, if we simply do as you mentioned, the parameter value will not be incremented. Let me clarify the eventual output, please see the updated question soon...

Comment: Ok now I see what you mean. What you can do is create a temporary file with the parameters after the `$a` loop with `echo $t, $a`. After you created the calculation file you can use the command `paste` to horizontally merge the two files.